# Adding a Class to an <img> Getting From Post Content

Tags: wordpress

Can you please let me know how I can add a class to an image getting from Post Content?
I have a page called `promotion` and it only contains an image which I uploaded through `Add Media` now in page I have

```
<div class="container">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>  
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>  
</div>
```

and at front end I am getting this:

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-2202 alignright" src="http://rumioptical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Promotion-Banner.jpg" alt="Promotion Banner" width="800" height="640">
```

but I need only to get

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://rumioptical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Promotion-Banner.jpg" alt="Promotion">
```

removing the `size-full wp-image-2202 alignright` classes and `widtd and height` attributes and adding the `img-responsive`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the post using the text editor rather than the visual editor. Change the attributes in the HTML to match what you need:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://rumioptical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Promotion-Banner.jpg" alt="Promotion">
```